# objective-c searching array of dictionary with a list of keys

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there another way of filtering an array of dictionary using a predicate with multiple values?

for example: in SQL you can do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

in objective-c i have an NSArray with NSDictionary

I want all the elements in NSArray that contains a dictionary key = 1 or key=2 or key=3 etc..

My first thought was to loop through my keys that I am searching for.

```
KEYS = [1,2,3];

for each k in keys
{
   do my predicate stuff where key=k;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout `- (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate`.

NSPredicate is important to know, especially when working with Core Data, but it can be useful when filtering any collection.

Comment: I am using predicate. I guess I would have to build the predicate string with a bunch of ORs? Is there a clause I should be using?

Comment: Yes, you have a lot of possible operators available. The one you want is likely the `IN` operator. Check out the docs for more: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Comment: Yep. I just saw IN was an operator. Thanks. Should have checked that first.